# Как написать функцию по графику?

Tags: php, график

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется вот такая зависимость. Реально ли по ней вывести формулу? Подскажите  примерный алгоритм действий

Comment: Есть различные методы аппроксимации и интерполяции. Здесь, судя по всему, нужно интерполировать квадратичной или экспоненциальной функцией. Но это уже касается математики, а не программирования.

Comment: Мне нужно это для php скрипта. Зависимость цены от количества доступных скачиваний

Comment: Неважно, для чего это нужно, непосредственно к программированию отношения данный вопрос не имеет. Поищите методы интерполяции (если вам важно, чтобы функция проходила точно по точкам, заданным в таблице) или аппроксимации (самый простой - метод наименьших квадратов) экспоненциальной функцией, затем изучите, как данные методы реализовываются численно, и напишите программу на PHP.

Comment: Попробую. О результате отпишу

Comment: `$allow_downloads=round(-(7.0243475*10**(-15))*$out_summ**6+(1.4525147*10**(-11))*$out_summ**5-(8.1453436*10**(-9))*$out_summ**4+(2.7681261*10**(-7))*$out_summ**3+0.001363*$out_summ**2+0.003304*$out_summ+1.4392041);`
Вот такая формула вышла кому интересно. Получил с помощью программы Advanced Grapher -> Вычисления -> Регрессионный анализ

Comment: https://k-tree.ru/statiy/statistika/prognozirovanie/prostoi_primer_lineinoi_regressii - в конце статьи формулы, как рассчитывается